# Error popups don't disappear after submitting a comment

Tags: bug, comments, error-message, popups

Steps to reproduce this error:

1. Type something that will notify two users into the comment textbox. E.g

   ```
   @user @user2 Hello!
   ```
2. You will see an error message with

   > Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified
3. Don't close the popup. Now, change the text you typed into a valid one, E.g:

   ```
   @user Hello! Hi
   ```
4. Submit the comment.
5. Press the "*add a comment*" text again.

Result: Popup still resides.

> [image]

Comment: Browser(s) used?

Comment: @ShadowWizard , Reproduced with Chrome 43.0.2357.124